# Read File by Splitting Each Row in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I am trying to read the File by Splitting each Row by removing whitespace through regex.split in c# but my code isn't working properly need help. Thanks in Advance.

```
        text="";
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream filestream = open.OpenFile();
            if (filestream != null)
            {
                string filename = open.FileName;
                text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            }


            string code = textBox1.Text;
            columncounter = code.Length;
            string[] arrays = Regex.Split(code, @"\s+");
            textBox1.Text = text;

        }
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Seems, that you're just *ignoring* split results - `string[] arrays`, since you assign `text` (`textBox1.Text = text;`)

Comment: I have added a foreach loop in the string array `foreach (string s in arrays)
            { textbox.text = s; }`

Comment: But that doesn't helps me out. to Split a row from the File is their any other way to do that ? Please

Comment: Wrap the `Stream` with a `StreamReader` and you can call `ReadLine()` on that.

Comment: Your should update your code sample if you added a foreach. But in your foreach, you are just reassigning the .text property over and over. Perhaps you should do: `textbox.Text += Environment.NewLine + s;`

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you are trying to do. Write all the text without any whitespace to the textbox? write each word on a new line in the text box? write each line (row) on a new line in the textbox?

Comment: You also never use the 'columncounter' variable. What are you trying to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to write each row, without whitespace, to your TextBox, this should work:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename))
{
    result.AppendLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"\s", "")));
}

textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

For faster performance, use string.Replace:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename))
{
    result.AppendLine(line
        .Replace("\t", "")
        .Replace("\n", "")
        .Replace("\r", "")
        .Replace(" ", ""));
}

textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: If the point is to remove white spaces, just use replace instead of a concat and a split.

Comment: @Fjodr Updated with replace. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `textBox1.text = string.Concat(arrays)`. It will concatenate the strings from the splitted array.

or you could do something like text.Replace(" ", "")